# file_get_contents + stream_context_create works on 1 server, blocked on another

Tags: php, file-get-contents

We have 2 servers, dev and live. They both use LAMP (Debian), but the dev server is regular http and the live server is https. This code works perfectly on our dev server:

```
$all_data = array(...);
$eol = "\r\n";

$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen(json_encode($all_data)),
    'connection: close'
);
$headers = implode($eol, $headers);

$opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => $headers,
        'content' => json_encode($all_data)
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);


$update_data = file_get_contents($_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $system_file, null, $context);
```

On the live server, the file_get_contents gives this error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://...): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in ....php on line 1086
```

I have looked at the apache logs for clues as to what is causing it to fail on the live server, but I only see the error above. It doesn't say what's blocking the call. I have allow_url_include and allow_url_fopen set to On on the live server.

I don't know if it's something in the Apache configuration or the SSL configuration, or something else, and I don't know where to look. I spent several hours today researching this issue and tried adding different headers to the headers array (User-Agent, Accept-Language, Accept-Encoding, Cookie, etc.), but nothing worked. I basically tried to replicate what was on dev, but live just didn't like it.

I also verified that if I copy and paste the URL that's being created directly in the browser that it works, so I know the filename is correct.

```
 dev server:
 php: 5.6.14-0+deb8u1
 apache: Apache/2.4.10
 debian: 8.2

 live server:
 php: 5.5.12
 apache: Apache/2.4.10
 debian: 7.9
```

Comment: Connection timed out sounds like a firewall issue. Have you pinged the destination from the live server, or better run nmap on port 443?

Comment: Try making the https request manually from the commandline via `curl` on the server where it's not working. Just: `curl https://...`

Comment: @JeffPuckettII, I tried this: nmap -p 443 ourdomain.com and got this: PORT    STATE    SERVICE
443/tcp filtered https

Comment: @will, we are installing curl now and will try it.

Comment: Update: I couldn't get it to work using file_get_contents after trying everything I could find online, so I instead decided to use exec('php -f ...') to run the program from the command line. I then took the json_encoded contents and file_put_contents them into a file, and had the command-line program read in the contents of the file. This workaround worked.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please use proxy and try

```html
$aContext = array(
    'http' => array(
        'proxy' => 'tcp://192.168.0.2:3128',
        'request_fulluri' => true,
    ),
);
$cxContext = stream_context_create($aContext);

$sFile = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com", False, $cxContext);

echo $sFile;
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I got the same error that it timed out.

Comment: Is there any firewall issues between both servers ? If you have those issues please open the port and try again with proxy..                                         try with **telnet** or **ping** command